# Webmethod returning Arraylist with a collection of objects

Tags: c#, web-services, arraylist

I have a `webmethod` that returns an `ArrayList` containing 4 objects:

```
    public class Getdata
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int TagID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public ArrayList GetValues()
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        Getdata employee1= new Getdata()
        {
            Name="Sathya",
            TagID=10,
            Address="Chennai"
        };
        Getdata employee2= new Getdata()
        {
            Name="Ram",
            TagID=11,
            Address="Chennai"
        };
        Getdata employee3= new Getdata()
        {
            Name="Pandi",
            TagID=12,
            Address="Chennai"
        };
        Getdata employee4= new Getdata()
        {
            Name = "Karthick",
            TagID = 13,
            Address = "Chennai"
        };
        list.Add(employee1);
        list.Add(employee2);
        list.Add(employee3);
        list.Add(employee4);

        return list;
    }
```

But here I just want to retrieve (display) the `Name` of all these employees. How can I do it in the UI?

And this is my method calling this `webmethod`:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeeWebService obj = new EmployeeWebService ();
        ArrayList list = obj.GetValues();//Calling webmethod
        //foreach (object o in list)
        //Response.Write(o);
    }
```

Output should be:

```
Sathya
Ram
Pandi
Karthick
```

Comment: Use List<GetData> instead of ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
public class Getdata
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public List<GetData> GetValues()
{
    var list = new List<GetData>();
    Getdata employee1= new Getdata()
    {
        Name="Sathya",
        TagID=10,
        Address="Chennai"
    };
    Getdata employee2= new Getdata()
    {
        Name="Ram",
        TagID=11,
        Address="Chennai"
    };
    Getdata employee3= new Getdata()
    {
        Name="Pandi",
        TagID=12,
        Address="Chennai"
    };
    Getdata employee4= new Getdata()
    {
        Name = "Karthick",
        TagID = 13,
        Address = "Chennai"
    };
    list.Add(employee1);
    list.Add(employee2);
    list.Add(employee3);
    list.Add(employee4);

    return list;
}




protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmployeeWebService obj = new EmployeeWebService ();
    var list = obj.GetValues();//Calling webmethod
    foreach (var item in list) 
    {
        Response.Write(item.Name + "<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry - not paying close attention.  Change those ArrayLists to List<GetData>.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Therefore it is not possible with ArrayList to get the Name alone??

Comment: ArrayLists can be used to hold objects of any type, and as such, when you pull items from an ArrayList they have to be cast to their proper type.  On the other hand, the generic List<> contains items of a specific type and there is no need to cast their contents when accessed.  You can use ArrayList, but you have to take care to cast properly.  On the other hand, if you use List<>, you'll find that it will work for you automatically.